# Demon Queen Reincarnation?

Tags: story-identification, manga

This is what I do remember hopefully it is all correct and relevant information. I believe the story starts with a person who wakes up hundreds or thousands of years later. She was the demon queen or something with equivalent power. She wakes up to the only servant in her I believe to be a castle. Once she gets oriented she then goes to look at the outside world which is now peaceful because of her death.

She is now not recognized by anyone where before they feared just the sight of her. Also it took many powerful hero's teamed up to kill her. After exploring for a bit she then asks the one servant (who I believe is an amalgamation because she has survived for such a longtime) where her generals are. Before she was killed she had I believe it to be 4 or 8 generals that were under her command and even after her death they could not be destroyed yet people still try.

She proceeds to search for her generals/followers which I believe are called something related to the stars. Her appearance from what I remember and this could be wrong was white hair with a silver skin tone and wings (not sure if it was more demon like wings or angel like).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is *[Yasei no Last Boss ga Arawareta!](https://myanimelist.net/manga/109032/Yasei_no_Last_Boss_ga_Arawareta)*, or *A Wild Final Last Appeared!*

The main character wakes up in the body of his game character, Lufasu, after using her as the final boss of an MMO.  The people who summoned him are upset that, not only did their hero summoning fail, but it undid the seal on the Supreme Ruler. After scaring everyone in the room, he manages to determine that the time is 200 years after Lufasu was defeated in the game. He then goes to his home base from the game, and finds a servant there.

After that they go out and explore the world, reconnecting with Lufasu's subordinates. The subordinates were named after the Zodiac signs and even 200 years later are some of the strongest beings in the world. Lufasu is an angel with blond hair and dark angel wings.